# Solving Exponential PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can anyone help me solve this? I am having a hard time figuring this out.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x+y$

Answer (score 2):

The equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x+y$ can be rewritten as $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$ where $P(x)=-1$ and $Q(x)=e^x$. The general solution for $y$ can then be found through the well known [method of integrating factors](http://www.cse.salford.ac.uk/physics/gsmcdonald/H-Tutorials/ordinary-differential-equations-integrating-factor.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}y\right)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $y=z\, e^x$ to get $z'=1$